# Improve performance of UPDATE WHERE sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

I have a quite simple query

```
UPDATE TableA
SET date_type = TableB.date_type
FROM TableB
WHERE TableB.int_type = TableA.int_type
```

My indices are:
`TableA(int_type)`, `TableB(int_type, date_type)`

`EXPLAIN` results:

```
Update on TableA  (cost=2788789.320..34222368.900 rows=82594592 width=261)
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=2788789.320..34222368.900 rows=82594592 width=261)
          Hash Cond: (TableA.int_type = TableB.int_type)
        ->  Seq Scan on tableA  (cost=0.000..12610586.960 rows=101433296 width=247)
        ->  Hash  (cost=1272403.920..1272403.920 rows=82594592 width=18)
              ->  Seq Scan on TableB  (cost=0.000..1272403.920 rows=82594592 width=18)
```

Query is in progress for more than 3 hours.

What can be done to make it run faster? As I can see from the `EXPLAIN` results, indices are not used.  Should I pick other indices/make any other improvement to have query running faster?

Postgresql 9.6

Comment: How many matching rows from `tableB.int_type` do you  expect for every `tableA.int_type` ? (tableB appears to be larger...) PK/FK relation between the two?

Comment: @wildplasser all (around 80 millions) records from `tableB` will go to the `tableA` (120 millions). One-to-one relation. No PK/FK relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do, is avoid idempotent updates:

---

```
UPDATE TableA a
SET date_type = b.date_type
FROM TableB b
WHERE b.int_type = a.int_type
AND a.date_type IS DISTINCT FROM b.date_type  -- <<-- avoid updates with the same value
        ;
```

---

And, maybe you assume a 1-to-1 relation between A and B, but the DBMS does not.
You could restrict the updates to at most one source row per target row:

---

```
EXPLAIN
UPDATE TableA a
SET date_type = b.date_type
FROM ( SELECT int_type, date_type
        , row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY int_type) AS rn
        FROM TableB
        ) b
WHERE b.int_type = a.int_type
AND a.date_type IS DISTINCT FROM b.date_type -- <<-- avoid idempotent updates
AND b.rn=1 -- <<-- allow only one update per target row.
        ;
```

Comment: any recommendation on the index?

Comment: Since you didn't show the index definition, I cannot comment on that.

Comment: My indices are: `TableA(int_type)`, `TableB(int_type, date_type)`

Comment: That is not a definition. DDL please.

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
UPDATE TableA
SET date_type = TableB.date_type
FROM TableB
WHERE TableB.int_type = TableA.int_type
```

You can try an index on `TableB(int_type, date_type)`.